# Migrating from Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus to Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I have been trying to migrate my code base to latest ServiceBus SDK and unable to find a method which can serialize a binary body to a source object.

In the past I use to retrieve the object as below:

```
receivedMessage.GetBody<RemoteExecutionContext>(
                   new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RemoteExecutionContext)));
```

How do I archive similar result in new library?

Comment: the from & to is identical... maybe you should mention the versions.

Comment: Can you clarify which SDK you're moving to?   The title suggests that you're migrating from the current generation, `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`, to a legacy package.   If you're attempting to move from `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` to `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`, I believe [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample08_Interop.md) illustrates the interop scenario that you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

The sample below express how to interact with messages that are sent using **WindowsAzure.ServiceBus** and received using **Azure.Messaging.Service**. To serialize the **BrokeredMessage** body the **WindowsAzure.ServiceBus** uses **DataContractSerializer**. Which helps in working with this library, below steps are required in sending messages through WindowsAzure.ServiceBus.

```
ServiceBusReceiver receiver = client.CreateReceiver(queueName);

ServiceBusReceivedMessage received = await receiver.ReceiveMessageAsync();

// Similar to the send scenario, we still rely on the DataContractSerializer and we use string as our type because we are expecting a JSON
// message body.
var deserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(string));
XmlDictionaryReader reader =
    XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(received.Body.ToStream(), XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);

// deserialize the XML envelope into a string
string receivedJson = (string) deserializer.ReadObject(reader);

// deserialize the JSON string into TestModel
TestModel output = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestModel>(receivedJson);
```

For more information check [ServiceBus link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample08_Interop.md).